# motionBegan:withEvent: not called in AppDelegate in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uikit, ios10, uiresponder

I used to detect a shake motion from the AppDelegate by simply implementing this method:

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"shake shake shake");
}
```

which works fine in iOS 8 and 9. However it doesn't work in iOS 10 anymore.
I also tried adding

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
        return YES;
}
```

but that didn't help. This works fine in the UIViewControllers though. Did something change in iOS 10, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue as you. Instead of implementing it on AppDelegate, I now use UIWindow, which works for me in iOS 8-10. Perhaps this is do-able for you as well?

```
extension UIWindow {

    override open var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override open func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            //logic here
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do it even cleaner, you might be able to set a specialized version of the UIWindow on the application.

Comment: Thanks @jayjunck. I fixed it in my code by moving this logic into the root view controller. I'm sure there are a lot of workarounds, but they still don't explain why it is not working in AppDelegate. AppDelegate is a UIResponder, so it should work...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I tried [@jayjunck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643849/jayjunck)'s answer but Xcode thrown `Method does not override any method from its superclass`. I fixed it by replacing `public` with `open` to access and override `motionBegan` function
In Swift 3,

- An `open` class is accessible and subclassable outside of the defining module. An open class member is accessible and overridable outside of the defining module.
- A `public` class is accessible but not subclassable outside of the defining module. A public class member is accessible but not overridable outside of the defining module.

enter code here

```
extension UIWindow {
override open func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.motionBegan(motion, with: event)

        guard motion == UIEventSubtype.motionShake else { 
            return 
        }

        // Shake is detected 
    }
}
```

Swift 5

```
extension UIWindow {
        open override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
            super.motionBegan(motion, with: event)

            guard motion == UIEvent.EventSubtype.motionShake else {
                return
            }

            // Shake is detected
        }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You should override **motionBegan** method in (all) View Controller(s).

Comment: It works fine in view controllers, it's not the problem. I need it to work in the AppDelegate.